# Rounded corners in relative layouts

Tags: android, rounded-corners

I want rounded corners in layout.

I make a shape for this with corners attributes specified, but when running, the corners of the top doesnt change. The ones of the botton does.

So why the top corners are not changing?

Custom header red

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="#EBEBEB"/>
            <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
            android:topRightRadius="15dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
            />

    </shape>
```

Custom layout saldos

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
            android:topRightRadius="15dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
            />

    </shape>
```

Heres the Framelayout xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment.AllAccountsFragment">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F1F1F1"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_layout_saldos"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerTotal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_header_red">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
                android:background="@drawable/coins"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="SALDO TOTAL"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgTotalPesos"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mex_bw"/>

        <com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTotalPesos"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgTotalPesos"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="57dp"
            android:text="MN"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgTotalDolares"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/usa_bw"/>

        <com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTotalDolares"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:textSize="13dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgTotalDolares"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="57dp"
            android:text="USD"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerCheques"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#EBEBEB">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Cuentas de Cheques"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgChequesPesos"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mex_bw" />

        <com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtChequesPesos"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:text="MN"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgChequesDolares"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/usa_bw" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgChequesArrow"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_gray" />

        <com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtChequesDolares"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
            android:text="USD"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerCredilinea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="#EBEBEB">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="Credilinea"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCredilinea"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mex_bw"/>

        <com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCredilinea"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:textSize="13dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:text="MN"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCredilineaArrow"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_gray" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerCreditos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="#EBEBEB">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="Tarjetas de crédito"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCreditos"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mex_bw"/>

        <com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCreditos"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:textSize="13dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:text="MN"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCreditosArrow"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_gray" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerTPV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="#EBEBEB">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:text="Terminal Punto de Venta"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgTPV"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mex_bw"/>

        <com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTPV"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:textSize="13dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:text="MN"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgTPVArrow"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_gray" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="190dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerFondos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="#EBEBEB">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="Fondos de Inversión"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgFondos"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mex_bw"/>

        <com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtFondos"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:textSize="13dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:text="MN"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgFondosArrow"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_gray" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerPagares"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="#EBEBEB">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="Pagarés"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPagares"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mex_bw"/>

        <com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPagares"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:textSize="13dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:text="MN"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPagaresArrow"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_gray" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="190dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerSeguros"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="#EBEBEB">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="Seguros de Auto"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSeguros"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mex_bw"/>

        <com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSeguros"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:textSize="13dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:text="MN"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSegurosArrow"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_gray" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

This is a image of the output the phone

[image]

Comment: Please share full Framelayout xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update (based on new shared xml)

Basically I replaced your used `drawable` images with `"@mipmap/ic_launcher"` and I can see everything is working fine already. No changes are made. Tested in Nexus 5 (api 23 device) and Pixel 2 (Api 23) AVD.

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment.AllAccountsFragment">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F1F1F1"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_layout_saldos"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerTotal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_header_red">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="SALDO TOTAL"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgTotalPesos"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTotalPesos"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgTotalPesos"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="57dp"
            android:text="MN"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgTotalDolares"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTotalDolares"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgTotalDolares"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="57dp"
            android:text="USD"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerCheques"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#EBEBEB">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Cuentas de Cheques"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgChequesPesos"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtChequesPesos"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:text="MN"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgChequesDolares"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgChequesArrow"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtChequesDolares"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
            android:text="USD"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerCredilinea"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="#EBEBEB">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Credilinea"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCredilinea"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCredilinea"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
            android:text="MN"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCredilineaArrow"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerCreditos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="#EBEBEB">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Tarjetas de crédito"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCreditos"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCreditos"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
            android:text="MN"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCreditosArrow"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerTPV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="#EBEBEB">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Terminal Punto de Venta"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="12dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgTPV"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTPV"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
            android:text="MN"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgTPVArrow"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerFondos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="#EBEBEB">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Fondos de Inversión"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgFondos"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtFondos"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
            android:text="MN"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgFondosArrow"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerPagares"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="#EBEBEB">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Pagarés"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPagares"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPagares"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
            android:text="MN"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPagaresArrow"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerSeguros"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="#EBEBEB">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Seguros de Auto"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSeguros"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSeguros"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
            android:text="MN"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSegurosArrow"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

### Original (based on OP's initially shared layout xml)

Every corner is having `15dp` radius but you `headerTotal` layout is placing on top thus hiding the top corners. May be some padding on the container layout or the margin on `headerTotal` would help. But again depends on your design target what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: sorry ignore no the activity name :D its just something I use for SO to try out different codes

Comment: that's why I place also corner radious for the Custom header red, why is not rounding in that shape?

Comment: He updated the layout while I was writing the answer.

Comment: @arnoldssss, the layout xml that you posted first in the question, the red has also corner radius but I can't try your new layout code cause I don't have the drawables.

Answer (score 1):

**For API 21 or above**

Use [Clip Views](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping#Clip)

It says,

> Clipping views enables you to easily change the shape of a view. You
> can clip views for consistency with other design elements or to change
> the shape of a view in response to user input. You can clip a view to
> its outline area using the [`View.setClipToOutline()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setClipToOutline(boolean)) method. Only
> rectangle, circle, and round rectangle outlines support clipping, as
> determined by the `Outline.canClip()` method.
>
> To clip a view to the shape of a drawable, set the drawable as the
> background of the view (as shown above) and call the
> [`View.setClipToOutline()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setClipToOutline(boolean)) method.
>
> Clipping views is an expensive operation, so don't animate the shape
> you use to clip a view. To achieve this effect, use the [Reveal Effect](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations#Reveal)
> animation.

```
<!-- res/drawable/myrect.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#42000000" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```